# Catalyst не подключает Template Toolkit

Tags: perl

Делаю первое приложение на Catalyst Framework, всё строго по книге The Definitive Guide to Catalyst. Однако при попытке создать шаблон, используя Template Toolkit с помощью этой команды:

```
script/lolcatalyst_lite_create.pl view Web TT
```

получаю ошибки:

> `exists "/home/fladex/LolCatalyst-Lite/script/../lib/LolCatalyst/Lite/View"`
> `exists "/home/fladex/LolCatalyst-Lite/script/../t"`
> `Couldn't load helper "Catalyst::Helper::View::TT"`, `"Can't locate Catalyst/Helper/View/TT.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /home/fladex/LolCatalyst-Lite/script/../lib /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.3/i586-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.3 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.12.3/i586-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.12.3 /usr/lib/perl5/5.12.3/i586-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.12.3 .) at (eval 225) line 2.`

Подскажите, что нужно исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам модуль для каталиста установлен?

```
cpanm install "Catalyst::View::TT"
```

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло :)
Я ориентировался на книгу, где сказано "Template Toolkit is used in Catalyst::Helper, so it will always be on a machine that has already had Catalyst::Devel installed.". А его я устанавливал, поэтому и думал, что все нужные модули установлены.